# How can report to google that the reporter of a DMCA request not copyright owner?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, blackhat, dmca

For a removed URL by Google DMCA report, how can report to google that the reporter of a DMCA request not copyright owner?

Comment: Can you explain the scenario?? As is stands, if it not yours or you are not involved, then do you have standing? That would be the question even if you were to report any issue. If the complaint filed is against you, then I assume you have some sort of mechanism available, however, to make a recommendation, I suspect that would be important to know.

Comment: This is short scenario: A person fills form of DMCA as owner of a content (fake copyright owner). Now how we can report that this person is fake owner, is there any form or contact info for this problem?

Comment: I am not sure since I have only very recently had to face this issue. I assume that there is some recourse if the complaint is made against your site. Otherwise, I do not believe there is such an option, at least, not with Google. There may be options on some of the other DMCA sites. I have not investigated any of these yet. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer. I am not qualified or licensed to give legal advice. That said, here is my opinion:

Google has a process for DMCA claims related to it. File a counter notification with Google as described [here](https://support.google.com/legal/answer/1120734), towards the bottom of the page.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to lawyer up as the DMCA process is kind of broken with respect to things like [copyfraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyfraud).

Comment: With respect, the OP is not asking about how to file a DMCA complaint, but rather how to respond to a DMCA complaint. Whether they are the target of the complaint is not clear. Any answer appears to depend upon this.

Comment: @closetnoc You either file a DMCA take down notice or a DMCA take down counter notice depending on what role you have. There's nothing else outside of taking it to court. If OP is a third party, with no legal responsibility regarding the alleged copyright, they have no legal recourse and cannot make a notification or a counter notification.

Comment: It sound like the OP is a third-party. Good info! Cheers!!